# Mocking a view in Laravel

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, laravel-4, mockery

I've just started out with Mockery. I'm trying to mock my view in Laravel, but can't quite get it right. This is what I have..

Controller action:

```
public function signup()
{
    return View::make(
        'account.signup',
        array(
            'pageHeading'   => 'Signup',
            'profileTypes'  => $this->profileTypeRepository->all()
        )
    );
}
```

Test:

```
public function testSignupView()
{
    $this->profileTypeRepositoryInterfaceMock
        ->shouldReceive('all')
        ->once()
        ->andReturn($this->mock('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection'));

    View::shouldReceive('make')
        ->once()
        ->with('account.signup', array(
            'pageHeading' => \Mockery::type('string'),
            'profileTypes' => $this->profileTypeRepositoryInterfaceMock
        ));
}
```

However this does't work:

```
1) AccountControllerTest::testSignupView
Mockery\Exception\NoMatchingExpectationException: No matching handler found for     Mockery_5_Illuminate_View_Factory::make("account.signup", array('pageHeading'=>'Signup','profileTypes'=>'object(Mockery_4_Illuminate_Database_Eloquent_Collection)',)). Either the method was unexpected or its arguments matched no expected argument list for this method
```

If I assign data to the view using the `with()` method, I can test it like so:

Controller action:

```
public function signup()
{
    return View::make(
        'account.signup'
    )->with('pageHeading', 'Signup')
     ->with('profileTypes', $this->profileTypeRepository->all());
}
```

Test:

```
public function testSignupView()
{
    View::shouldReceive('make')
        ->once()
        ->with('account.signup')
        ->andReturn(\Mockery::self())
        ->shouldReceive('with')
        ->with('pageHeading', \Mockery::type('string'))
        ->andReturn(\Mockery::self())
        ->shouldReceive('with')
        ->with('profileTypes', \Mockery::any());

    $this->get('signup');
}
```

However, I don't want to do this; I'd like to pass the full array of data as the second argument.

How can I test the view while passing the data as the second argument to the View facade?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `->with('profileTypes', $this->profileTypeRepository->all());` in the controller is what's causing the problem. the all() function returns an eloquent collection, and, in your test, `$this->profileTypeRepositoryInterfaceMock` likely is not an eloquent collection, which is why you get the NoMatchingExpectationException.

You'll want to change the expectation for profileTypes so that it expects an eloquent collection.